# Invalid expression Using scrapy parser to extract Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract certain attribute value from a `HTML` response. The specific element I am interested in looks like below

```
<meta property="x:y:z" content="interesting">
```

I am using following code to extract "interesting" part. Its giving me `Invalid expression`. I even validated the expression using a third party tool to generate `XPath`.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

req = requests.get(some_url, headers=user_agent)
hxs = Selector(req)
links = hxs.xpath('//meta[@property="x:y:z"]@content')
```

Any clues?

Comment: You lost slash - `//meta[@property="x:y:z"]/@content`

Answer (score 1):

use <kbd>/</kbd> before @content and `extract()` at the end:

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

req = requests.get(some_url, headers=user_agent)
hxs = Selector(req)
links = hxs.xpath('//meta[@property="x:y:z"]/@content').extract()
#result: ['interesting']
```